# Select rows of multiple tables via joins

Tags: postgresql, join

I have some tables which are related to each others.

A short demonstration:

Sites:

```
 id | clip_id | article_id | unit_id
--------------+------------+--------
  1 | 123     |  12        |  7
```

Clips:

```
id | title  | desc |
------------+--------
 1 | foo2   | abc1
```

Articles:

```
id | title  | desc | slug
------------+---------------------
 1 | foo2   | abc1 | article.html
```

Units:

```
 id | vertical_id | title |
------------------+-------+
  1 | 123         |  abc  |
```

Verticals:

```
id | name  | 
-----------+
 1 | vfoo  |
```

Now I want to do something like below:

```
SELECT ALL VERTICAL, UNIT, SITE, CLIP, ARTICLE attributes 
from VERTICAL, UNIT, SITE, CLIP, ARTICLE TABLES 
WHERE vertical_id = 2
```

Can some one help me how can I use `joins` for this?

Comment: Post the schemas of `vertical` and `clip`. It is necessary to know the columns on which to join.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a running example of possibly what you want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/af63b/2

```
select * from
sites
inner join units on sites.unit_id=units.id
inner join clips on clips.id=sites.clip_id
inner join articles on articles.id=sites.article_id
inner join verticals on verticals.id=units.vertical_id
where units.vertical_id=123
```

The problem is, that the description you gave us did not clearly specify which columns to join:

1. **(answered)** Why does `units` have a link to `site` via `site_id` and `sites` a link back to `units` via `unit_id`?
2. **(answered)** Why does `units` have a link to `verticals` via `vertical_id` and `verticals` a link back to `units` via `unit_id`?

I am guessing that your data does not giva a consistent example to get rows using the join. For `vertical_id=123` there is no corresponding entry in `verticals`.

**Edit:**

I corrected the SQL due to corrections within the question. With this the two questions are answered.

Comment: Sorry, the `site_id` and `unit_id` in Unit and vertical tables was a typo.

Comment: So the correct link would be sites.unit_id=units.id?

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.id, s.clip_id, s.article_id, u.title, u.vertical_id, c.title, v.unit_id, c.desc, a.slug 
from sites s
join units u on s.id = u.id
join clips c on u.id = c.id
join verticals v on c.id = v.id
join articles a on v.id = a.id
where v.vertical_id = 'any id'
```